# how to detect if the end of horizontal scrollbar is reached?

Tags: javascript

I have a div wich is scrollable horizontally. I want to know when I reach the end of it.

Is there is simple way to detect if the horizontal scrollbar is scrollable to one direction or the other?

Comment: `Math.abs(el.scrollLeft) === el.scrollWidth - el.clientWidth`

Comment: thank you @raina77ow that works for me

Answer (score -3):

To check the horizontal scrollbar you need to use

```
var scrollLeft = $('#div_id').scrollLeft();
```

You can then check if it's equal to the $('#div_id').width() and there's the end.